# Redirect Old urls to new urls via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I currently have a bunch of urls to redirect to their new urls: I basically have to remove 'blog' from the start and add the 'uri' in there:

```
redirect 301 /blog/posts/view/follow-twitter http://domain.net/posts/view/uri/follow-twitter

redirect 301 /blog/posts/view/around-the-corner http://domain.net/posts/view/uri/around-the-corner
```

This is the rest of the .htaccess I have:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://domain.net/uri/$1 [R=301]
```

edit:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/posts/view/(.*)$ http://domain.net/posts/view/uri/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: I think you are missing the 'uri' in the new urls.

Comment: Write I want to replace 'blog' with 'uri' next time :)

Comment: No, I don't want to replace anything. I need to add 'uri' which is in the middle and remove 'blog' which is in the beginning.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad, haven't scrolled to the end of code. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Remove L from [], just leave [R=301]